# Output name with Current Date

Tags: arcpy, date, model

My goal is to create a daily automated task using a model built from ArcGIS ModelBuilder, then exported to Python script. I would like the outputs of this model to have the name (Stat_) + today's date: "Stat_20170216"

I was able to do this in ModelBuilder with an in-line variable but would like this operation to work in the exported python script.

Here's a bit of Code from the script, with "Stat_%Date%" as the output name.

```
# Process: Summary Statistics
arcpy.Statistics_AddressModel(StandAdd_Done_View__2_, Stat_Date_, "StandAdd_Done.ADD_SN2 COUNT", "StandAdd_Done.ADDR_HN")
```

I'm a novice with Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [get today's date](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today), and then [format it as a string](http://strftime.org/) in the format you want.

```
>>> todayDate = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")
>>> print todayDate
20170216
```

You can incorporate this into your code:

```
todayDate = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")
arcpy.Statistics_AddressModel(StandAdd_Done_View__2_, todayDate, "StandAdd_Done.ADD_SN2 COUNT", "StandAdd_Done.ADDR_HN")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!